# New Hosting - Blank Page in Wordpress

Tags: migration

The organisation that hosts our Wordpress site (a Church Diocese) is migrating all their sites to a new host by moving the full cPanel configuration across. Our Wordpress site seems to have migrated OK with the exception of CiviCRM. When I access the CiviCRM menu in the Wordpress backend all I get now is a blank page.

Any ideas as to where I should look to resolve this problem?

Thanks for any help/hints.

Answer (score 1):

Blank page normally suggests a PHP error, so your error logs are a good place to start.